# How to get the current percentage utilization of each core of a processor using Java code

Tags: java

I have a situation where i need to get the utilization of each core of CPU. E.g. if I have a processor with 4 cores then the expected output is:

```
               Core-1          Core-2      Core-3        Core-4
Utilization    31.04           12.89       2.45          10.56
```

I tried using following code:

```
OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
System.out.println(operatingSystemMXBean.getSystemLoadAverage());
```

The above code segment has a two fold problem. Firstly on Win7 32-bit the output is -1.0 and secondly the name of the method `getSystemLoadAverage()` gives an intution that it only displays overall cpu utilization.

Kindly help me with this issue as how to get the utilization of each core of processor.

Thanks

Comment: Windows 7 and Java are system that are now made to work on several processor at a time, and the processor itself will split the work. anyway, what you're trying to attempt can't be done with java because it run in a virtual machine that don't have that power. What you want to do can be achieve in the task manager of windows setting affintiy of application to a core or using `nice` tool on linux i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SIGAR.  Their site says :

One API to access system information regardless of the underlying platform

I believe that is what you want. Have a look at their site: http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar

JavaSysMon is another library to look at: https://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon/wiki

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write your application multithreaded. Writing a single-threaded application , is not faster on a quad core than on a single core (theoretically). To take advantage of your CPU cores, you have to explicitly program a process for each core.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't need to run my application on all the cores. Instead I only need to retrieve the utilization of each core of processor. Like in task manager we have four graphs for 4 cores of the processor. So I just need to retrieve the numerical values of these graphs in my code.